# How To Control Keyboard Focus Inside a UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a simple `UserControl` Which contains some `TextBlock`s. Also I have some of my `UserControl`s in a `StackPanel`, Normally when I press arrow keys keyboard focus moves between `UserControl`s and that's the behavior I DON"T WANT.

I want to handle arrow keys press inside the `UserControl` and stop keyboard navigation normal behavior, Just like a `TextBox`. **How Can I Do That?**

```
<StackPanel  >
    <dtp:DatePicker  VerticalAlignment="Top"/> <!-- When I press down arrow key on this element, keyboard navigation moves to next element-->
    <dtp:DatePicker  VerticalAlignment="Top" DisplayType="DateOnly"/>
    <dtp:DatePicker  VerticalAlignment="Top" DisplayType="TimeOnly"/>
    <dtp:DatePicker  VerticalAlignment="Top" HasSeconds="False"/>
    <dtp:DatePicker  VerticalAlignment="Top" DisplayType="DateOnly" HasSeconds="False"/>
    <dtp:DatePicker  VerticalAlignment="Top" DisplayType="TimeOnly" HasSeconds="False"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: in general it shouldn't move ,, so the problem may is in your **DatePicker** Control ,, try to handle PreviewKeyDown of your **DatePicker** Control. or put the template of your **DatePicker**

Answer (score 1):

Normally, with controls just inside a StackPanel, simple controls don't lost focus when pressing an arrow key. You can try it with just this little test.

```
<StackPanel>
    <DatePicker/>
    <DatePicker/>
    <DatePicker/>
</StackPanel>
```

Maybe your problem is outside the `dtp:DatePicker` controls. Maybe you are putting the `StackPanel` in an `ItemTemplate` ?

Anyway, you can try to neutralize the arrow keys with the `PreviewKeyUp` event like this :

```
<dtp:DatePicker PreviewKeyUp="OnPreviewKeyUp"/>

private void OnPreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Or you can try to put a navigation constraint with [Navigation mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<dtp:DatePicker KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="None" 
                KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"/>
```